# Need help on returning a list in a function in python

Tags: python, list, function, return, append

i need to do this 
Create 3 lists, one for red, one for green and one for blue, each containing 256 elements all initialized to 0
For every pixel in the image: Get the amount, r, of red from the pixel Increment position r in the red list Get the amount, g, of green from the pixel Increment position g in the green list Get the amount, b, of blue from the pixel Increment position b in the blue list
Return the red, green and blue lists
i wrote the code

`def colour():
        red=[0]*256
        for x in range(0, getWidth(img)):
                for y in range (0, getHeight(img)):
                        r= getPixel(img,getWidth(img) ,getHeight(img))
                        red.append(r)
        return (red)`
but for some reason i am unable to see the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be getting the same value from the image each time. You should probably be using `x` and `y` instead of `getWidth(img)` in the `getPixel` function inside your loop.

Also, since you are appending in the loop (and not writing to a certain position in the list `red`) you should just initialize an empty loop and not a bunch of zeroes. I'd try:

```
def colour():
    red = []
    for x in range(getWidth(img)):
        for y in range (getHeight(img)):
            r= getPixel(img,x,y)
            red.append(r)
    return red
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy, Take a look at this example.

```
>>> f= [9,5,4,3,2,7]
>>> g= ["p","o"]
>>> h= ["t","g"]
>>> def c():
    return f , g ,h

>>> c()
([9, 5, 4, 3, 2, 7], ['p', 'o'], ['t', 'g'])
```

Just remove the brackets around red , and if u want all the three list to be passed just do

```
return red, green ,blue
```